# Restarting crashed drivers on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am currently working on a NFC system using the ACR122U reader and not using the constructor drivers which lead to some occasionnal crashes of those drivers. 
The problem here is that when it crashes, the whole process isn't crashed, my program keep running but the drivers don't. (No need to say that it makes my code useless)
I am aware of the ways to restart a crashed program but not crashed drivers. I thought of using a watchdog to hard reset the raspberry but needless  to say that a reboot isn't the best choice because of the time it takes. ( I am using the very first Raspberry).
So, is there a way to reboot only the driver and more important, detect when it fails ?

Comment: If you are not using the constructor (manufacturer) drivers, why does it matter if they crash? Or if you are using the manufacture's drivers, why don't you try contacting the manufacturer for help?

Comment: It matters because I am running the system on my door. Pretty borring if they crash and my door stay locked ! I am using libnfc, it's an open source library...

Comment: I understand that you don't want anything to crash, what wasn't clear was what was actually crashing - so you are saying that libnfc has some component that is crashing?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Actually, I am using the libnfc library to communicate with the reader. At some point( can happen after 5 min or 5 hours), the message : "error libnfc.driver.acr122_usb command code verification failed" is issued. This is what I am trying to work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem after many hours of research and trials. The solution is actually very simple : just a background running script (my program in my case), and a check using grep, every two seconds :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

command="/your/path/to/your_script"
log="prog.log"

match="error libnfc"

matchnosp="$(echo -e "${match}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"

$command > "$log" 2>&1 &

pid=$!

while sleep 2
do
    if fgrep --quiet "$matchnosp" "$log"
    then
         echo "SOME MESSAGE"
         kill $(pidof your_script)
         $command > "$log" 2>&1 &
         sleep 5
         truncate -s 0 $log      
         echo "SOME OTHER MESSAGE..."
   fi
done
```

This restart the program when some message matching "error libnfc" is found in the log file.